Избежать бесконечного цикла
Есть функция. Если её вызвать, то она может уйти в бесконечный цикл. Как сделать так, чтобы спустя минуту без результата функция возвращала None?

В цикле есть возможность проверить время?

Нет, функция не изменяема.

Переписать эту функцию на нормальную. Потому что прерывать функцию, которая этого не желает и не дает возможностей (например async) можно только насильно. А это либо в отдельный процесс ее запихать, либо в thread, а потом магию типа этой со всеми вытекающими последствиями (в дотнете вон Abort не просто так запретили)

Запускаете в другом thread и убиваете его через минуту принудительно если он не отработал

Погуглите python timeout decorator, тут на СО тоже варианты какие-то найдутся.

Хочу обратить внимание на постановку задачи: согласно условию, функция уходит в бесконечный цикл, но при появлении результата неизвестно чем занимается. При отсутствии результата ещё круче логика - ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ None. А как же "уход в бесконечный цикл"?

Если речь идет про неизменную сложность алгоритма в цикле, то можно поставить селектор на количество итераций, равное по скорости нужному промежутку времени. Допустим, одна итерация протекает за Х микросекунд. То есть через 60000000/Х пройдёт примерно минута.
Если же сложность изменяется от итерации к итерации, можно в конце цикла поставить счетчик, рассчитывающий время выполнения в зависимости от условий данной итерации. При достижении счетчиком вышеупомянутого значения - выйти из цикла.
Чечтно говорю, в питоне не силен, но может сработать.

Консольная программка-идея:
import os
import time

def check_result(ok):
 if not ok: result = None
 else: result = True
 print(result)
 return result

while True:
 ok = False
 time.sleep(60)
 # Тут код проверки требуемого результата, если она успешна, ok = True
 check_result(ok)

os.system("pause")


Идея очень сырая, так как она просто переводит основной поток в режим ожидания на минуту.

А что, в условии автора требуется что-то иное? Я буду рад почитать Ваш вариант.

См. комментарии от vitidev и Daniil Loban под исходным вопросом.  Требуется обернуть запуск функции в отдельный поток хотя бы, который следует запустить с указанным таймаутом, чтобы через минуту этот поток был принудительно завершён / прерван.  Насколько такое решение подходит в общем случае, неизвестно, так как прерывание вызванной функции может иметь какие-нибудь серьёзные побочные эффекты.

Не хочу. Я не колю орехи кувалдой. Нет нужды в такой примитивной задаче гиперумствовать. Я написал - это идея. Не реализация чего-то там. И опять же я НЕ ВИЖУ ГОТОВОГО КОДА, я вижу только разговоры о коде.

при чём здесь "гиперумствовать"?  Представленный в данном ответе код НЕ является решением для исходного вопроса.  Сама идея запустить бесконечный цикл, подождать минуту на sleep, и проверить какое-то условие может быть приемлема, ЕСЛИ вы запустите в отдельном потоке/процессе исходную функцию до вашего цикла ожидания.  То есть будете проверять раз в минуту, не изменилось ли какое-то состояние. Или же используете какой-то асинхронный механизм с таймаутом для заданной функции.  P.S. Минус на ответе - не мой.

Не является? НЕ ПОЛЬЗУЙТЕСЬ! Ответ написан автору вопроса.

@FoxFox ответы не должны помогать лично автору вопроса, они должны становиться частью базы знаний, показывая, как можно решить конкретную проблему, обозначенную в вопросе.
